# Python Flask how to get all records from html table in a request post

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm learning `Flask` and I want to do a simple invoice app, but I don't have any idea of how to return back on post all data row from a table with
four fields `{code, description, price, quantity}` to be inserted or updated as the details to my DB table.

This is just a code example.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, DecimalField


app = Flask(__main__)

def save_invoice_det():
    # Here i'll iterate all rows got from the table
    pass


class DetailForm(FlaskForm):
    item_code = IntegerField('Item Code')
    item_desc = StringField('Description')
    quantity = DecimalField('Qty')
    price = DecimalField('Price', places=2)
    total = DecimalField('Total', places=2)


@app.route('/invoice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def invoice(number):
    form = DetailForm()

    # This is just example models table
    query_det = Details_Inv.query.get(number)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Here i need to know how to get all row from the table
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            save_invoice_det()
        return redirect(url_for('list_invoices'))

    return render_template('invoice.html', details=query_det)


if name == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


# invoice.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title>Create / Edit Invoice</title>
     </head>

    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
            <table>  <!-- This table with is what i want to return back in a request -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Descripction</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {% for detail in details %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ detail.item_code }}</td>
                            <td>{{ detail.item_desc }}</td>
                            <td>{{ detail.quantity }}</td>
                            <td>{{ detail.price }}</td>
                            <td>{{ detail.total }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It should have an option of `.all()` which will return all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if i am not wrong i guess you want to pass `details=form`, your form object.
Anyways there is no all() method that i know of, but you can have something like below,

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        save_invoice_det(form) # pass your form object
```

and in worker function you can have something as below,

```
attrs = vars(form)
for attr in attrs:
    if 'csrf_token' in attr:
        continue
    try:
        print(f'for {attr} field data is {getattr(form, attr).data}')
    except:
        pass
```

Basically `getattr(form, attr).data` is your solution.

Edit: I am using python 3.7 make adjustment according to your need

Edit: While looking at my answer you can have something like below too,

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, DecimalField
from flask import Flask
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

class CustomFlaskForm(FlaskForm):
    ignore_field = ['csrf_token']

    def all(self):
        val = OrderedDict()
        attrs = vars(self)
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr in self.ignore_field:
                continue
            try:
                val[attr] = getattr(self, attr).data
            except Exception as err:
                pass
        return val


class DetailForm(CustomFlaskForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DetailForm, self).__init__()
        self.ignore_field.append('total')

    item_code = IntegerField('Item Code')
    item_desc = StringField('Description')
    quantity = DecimalField('Qty')
    price = DecimalField('Price', places=2)
    total = DecimalField('Total', places=2)

with app.test_request_context() as app:
    form = DetailForm()
    print(form.all())
```

and output is:
`OrderedDict([('item_code', None), ('item_desc', None), ('quantity', None), ('price', None)])`

Comment: I'm trying fallow your examples, but i'm don't get it still.

Comment: I'm trying fallow your examples, but i'm don't get it still. I need a complete small detailed example, like some step by step. sorry for not be very smart. I need to be guided in how to read all data from the table then and how to send all the record to the template in render_template then how to populate the table with all these records and finally how to send all the records from the modified table back to a function to save each row from the table with those records to my db-table. Sorry again. I'll will appreciate all helps.

Comment: I would strongly recommend going through this tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world
specially chapter 3,4,5